# How do I get the Eclipse Groovy Compiler from bintray? Is it missing?

Tags: maven

I'm trying to obtain the lastest "Eclipse Groovy Compiler" and "Eclipse Groovy Batch Compiler" maven artifacts from [bintray.com](https://bintray.com/) in order to compile Groovy code via ["maven-compiler-plugin"](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) in a maven-ized Intellij IDEA project.

For example, the `groovy-eclipse-batch` artifact as described [here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Groovy-Eclipse-Maven-plugin) is supposed to be available from maven repository https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven (top right link on the page describing the artifact [here](https://bintray.com/groovy/maven/groovy-eclipse-batch)).

I want to pull down 2.4.13-02, which means configure the plugin repository in the POM:

```
   <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>bintray</id>
            <name>Groovy Bintray</name>
            <url>https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven</url>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Define the dependency (only showing the dependency on `groovy-eclipse-batch` here):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.13-02</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

...and add the dependency to the declaration of `maven-compiler-plugin` (here also shown: the dependency on `groovy-eclipse-compiler`):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <indy/>
                </compilerArguments>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <source>1.9</source>
                <target>1.9</target>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.2-04</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.13-02</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And this should be it.

However Intellij IDEA marks the version numbers of the dependencies in red and says it cannot find them. When running `mvn compile` on the command line I get:

*"Could not resolve dependencies for project foo:SomeJava9Project:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch:jar:2.4.13-02, org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-compiler:jar:2.9.2-04: Failure to find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch:jar:2.4.13-02 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced"*

What am I missing?

Comment: Uhhh hold on. I think it's just because I added explicit dependencies on `groovy-eclipse-batch` and `groovy-eclipse-compiler`? These seem not necessary, removing them makes Intellij IDEA pull down the needed artifacts from the repository. Success also on the command line...

Comment: But now I have "Failure executing groovy-eclipse compiler: Compliance level '1.4' is incompatible with target level '9'. A compliance level '9' or better is required" Oh yeah??